# Android Hardware Menu button isn't working for me

Tags: android, menu

I'm using this code to display a menu, but it isn't doing anything when I press the menu button.

This is in a view flipper, I don't know if that has anything to do with the problem.

I used this before and with no problems at all:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.new_game:

        return true;
    case R.id.help:
        finish();

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"

          android:title="new_game" />
    <item android:id="@+id/help"

          android:title="clear" />
</menu>
```

Comment: I just tried this and it works fine for me. Does logcat report any errors? Or is there an exception being thrown somewhere in other parts of your code?

This is defined in your activity and not in a subclass you made of the ViewFlipper correct?

Comment: yes this is in my activity.. and there in nothing..

Comment: Can you post the contents of your menu.xml file please?

Comment: there it is.. is like the button is never press

Comment: Not really without having your code to actually build. Maybe try on the emulator and see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the superclass methods.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to for options menus : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu

Comment: i have follow what this page tell me to do and it dosen't do anything eveloper.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu

Answer (score 0):

Dont you have to have some icon attached to it?

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_add"
```

for example